# Typecheck a TypeScript typed function call in a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I'm progressively migrating a JavaScript React app (CRA) to TypeScript. After having ran `npm i typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest` and `npx tsc --init`, I assigned types to a utility function, says

```js
export const toNumber = (s : string) : number => +s;
```

and changed the extension of the file containing it from `.js` to `.ts`.

Now, if I write

```
const n = toNumber(5);
```

in the very same `.ts` file, a typing error does show up on both `react-scripts start` and VSCode as expected. But if I import `toNumber` in a `.js` file and write the same expression, there is no error whatsoever.

Is it possible to enable typechecking of an imported TypeScript function in a `.js` file (while ignoring everything not typed)?